# How to setup a unversioned settings file and read from it in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have a settings file **settings.json**, which holds **api authorization key** that is required for the test project to run and successfully pass all the test cases.

I have included settings.json in the **.gitignore** so I do not accidentally publish the api authorization key to **github**.

The team city build is triggered when I do a check in to github repository. The test cases **fail** since settings.json does not exist in the repository.

When I run the project **locally**, I always copy the settings.json file to the **outputdirectory and the tests pass**.

How do I pass the **settings.json** in team city to build the project successfully, without checking in settings.json to github.

Testing Framework: **MSTest**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a powershell script step in teamcity and specify the script content in the step definition.   The script will create the json file.  Make sure the step is before your unit test step.   You can create a build configuration variable to store the apikey, and use teamcity variable replacement in the script body.

This assumes you're the only one that will be accessing the teamcity server.

Comment: Thank you @Andy. Your approach worked. This is the script that I wrote @{ApiAuthKey="%ApiAuthKey%"} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File settings.json. Additionally, I had to change the working directory in the powershell build step to **TestProject\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1**, since I always output the **settings.json** to output directory and it is read from there when run locally.